# VBA code works with F8 but not when run

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, charts

I have written some VBA code to insert an Embedded Picture into an Embedded Chart onto an Excel worksheet. The routine attempts to do this by copying the picture, adding an embedded chart, setting dimensions to the picture's dimensions, and then pasting the picture.

The thing is, it works with no errors when I step through it
with <kbd>F8</kbd> (“Debug” → “Step Into”). 
The code looks simple enough, and I've experimented with placement of the Copy/Paste sequence, and nothing seems to get the picture to completed that final Paste step when running the macro.

```
Sub EP()
Sheet9.Shapes("Picture 2").Copy
Dim xcht As Chart: Set xcht = Sheet9.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
    With xcht
        .ChartArea.ClearContents
        .ChartArea.Width = Sheet9.Shapes("Picture 2").Width
        .ChartArea.Height = Sheet9.Shapes("Picture 2").Height
        .Paste
    End With
End Sub
```

It works perfectly with <kbd>F8</kbd>; the picture is pasted into the chart. 
Just not when actually running –
I ran with the green play button in the VBA editor,
ran it through the macro dialog box,
and ran it through a button on the worksheet. 
No change in results.

What is going wrong? 
How can I get this routine to run correctly by normal invocation? 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What *does* happen when you run the code normally?

Comment: Do you get errors? What errors (the messages, not the numbers)? Where does the code stop, and what line is highlighted in yellow?

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the chart, so the .Paste goes somewhere:

```
Sub EP()
  Sheet9.Shapes("Picture 2").Copy
  Dim xcht As Chart
  Set xcht = Sheet9.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
  With xcht
    .ChartArea.Select
    .ChartArea.ClearContents
    .ChartArea.Width = Sheet9.Shapes("Picture 2").Width
    .ChartArea.Height = Sheet9.Shapes("Picture 2").Height
    .Paste
  End With
End Sub
```